# setup multiple git to push to single remote on staging branch then automate merge to master

Tags: git, github, git-remote

my current remote repo has 2 branches "master, test" 
what i need is to push multiple projects i have into this test branch, but i don't want to merge project on local so that i can keep every project history clean.

folder structure or localmachine
/client
/api
/admin
/docs
every folder has its own repo "local".

i want to push them all to "remote /test branch"
so than the test branch folder structure would contain all my repos (like local)

how can i achive this ? i've tried everthing online but most question address sync local to remote, and what i need is to sync "remote with local" without disrupting my workflow

**EDIT**

i managed to do what i need using following commands.

1. inside every local git i added another remote pointing to main repo
   `git remote add deploy git@git.website.com:usern/mainrepo.git`
2. checkout current creating a new branch
   `git branch -b stage-deploy`
3. add and commit repo to new branch
   `git add . && git commit -m"message"`
4. sync push this new branch with main repo
   `git push -u deploy`

now i have the content of this subproject deployed to banch `mainrepo/stage-deploy` next i merge this branch with test branch, since every project has its own folder, so no conflicts should happen.
after i merge, i delete the stage-deploy branch from both repos. and i'm done.

i do this inside every project and now i have all projects syncing to one repo, and this mainrepo/test has posthocs working to deploy to test server successfuly.

**remaining problem**
currently to merge the 'stage-deploy' branch with test branch i do it manual from the gitlab web interface. then i go back to local project and checkout delete the branch from local repo too,

how to automate merging newly created branch ?

Comment: I suggest maybe looking into using submodules: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: thanks, i tried it and followed steps but after i push to remote all that get pushed is a .gitmodules file pointing to the local directory on my machine that i cloned from `"url = /Users/Zalaboza/vhosts/api/client/.git"` the folder content where not pushed to remote

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you are asking is that multiple local repos will be sharing the same remote ref i.e the test branch. All local branches can be setup to track the remote test branch but won't push to it from multiple projects due to the fact that they do not agree on what the history looks like. Of course you can force push but that would eventually lead to the garbage collector deleting all your projects except the last one you pushed since it is the only one reachable while building the commit tree from refs.

With all this in mind, a way to do this is to create a branch for each project on the remote repo where the test branch points to (if it makes a difference you might want the test branch to have its own commits and is not still pointing to a commit on on the master branch). Then make each of your test branches on your local repos track its own branch on the remote repo. From there on you can push for example local master or test branches to their counter-branches on the remote repo.

One problem with all this is if have branches that have the same name in multiple repos. In this case you have to enforce unique branch names on the remote repo or make all your projects be in one repo and explore into things like namespaces and possibly multiple working trees.

Also you have to be careful to push only the branches you wanted and that are tracked properly, otherwise a push --all or a push --mirror could lead to headaches.

Comment: thanks, i ended up with something very similar and its working fine, except that i dont know how to automate merging branchs with test from terminal